# Operator overloading, destructor memory leak

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got a problem with destructor in my class.
The main idea is to use operator overloadings in undefined length vectors ex. u can create object which simulates a euclidian vector like RealVector(3) and then use function fillvec() to fill the table with positions x,y,z.

The problem is when I try to use a destructor to delete alocated memory for table.

Here is my code:

```
class RealVector{
   private:
      int dim;
      double* tab;
   public:
      RealVector(int dim){
         tab=new double[dim];
      }
      RealVector(const RealVector & other){
         dim=other.dim;
         tab=new double[other.dim];
         for(int i=0; i<dim; i++){
            tab[i]=other.tab[i];
         }
      }
      void fillvec(){
        for(int i=0; i<dim; i++){
            cin >> tab[i];
        }
      }
      void wri(){
        cout << "Vector [";
        for(int i=0; i<dim; i++){
            cout << tab[i];
            if(i!=dim-1)
                cout<<", ";
        }
        cout << "]";
      }
      RealVector operator+(RealVector & o){
         for(int i=0; i<dim; i++)
            tab[i]+=o.tab[i];
         return *this;
      }
      ~RealVector(){
          delete [] tab;
      }
}
int main(){
    RealVector* w1=new RealVector(3);
    RealVector* w2=new RealVector(3);
    RealVector* answerr=new RealVector(3);
    w1->fillvec();
    w2->fillvec();
    *answerr=*w1+*w2;
    answerr->wri();
}
```

Can someone explain where I have made mistake?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. `w1` is a pointer, you can'd do `w1.fillvec()`.

Comment: Your dtor is fine, but you need `delete w1; delete w2; delete answerr;`.

Comment: Also, in `RealVector(int dim){
         tab=new double[wymiar];
      }`, what is `wymiar`? Shouldn't it be `dim`?

Comment: There is Rule Of Three. There is no "rule of two".

Comment: I still got bad answer even when I use delete on pointers w1, w2, answerr.
w1->fillvec() works good
w2->fillves() works good
but when I create the answerr it got x=1.342553-306, y=0, z=0 (cause i know i just make new table not fill this table)  and after answerr=w1+w2 still no change this

Comment: Also if I'm not mistaken, because he doesn't have a user defined `operator=` when he copies the result into `answerr` it overwrites the pointer and orphans the memory on the heap.

Comment: You need to implement the assignment operator.

Comment: The other mistake is your main function having three `new` and six asterisks, which is about three `new` and six asterisks too many. Are you perhaps coming from Java background?

Comment: Works when I have changed 
RealVector operator+(RealVector & o)
to
RealVector & operator+(RealVector & o)

Comment: Yet another mistake is `operator+` modifying `*this`. When you do 2+5, and then reach for 2 for doing 2*3, do you expect to find 7 in its place?

Comment: @n.m. Do you want to maybe write an answer?

Comment: Consider not using pointers for `w1`, `w2`, and `answerr`. There doesn't seem to be any need, and not using pointers makes it much, much harder to have a memory leak.

Comment: Finally, if this is not a throwaway exercise for your school or something like that, you need to be using either `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: @Barry maybe later, I'm on a phone, not really good for typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see here few critical bugs.

*The first* one is the main (in your case) I think. The constructor `RealVector(int dim)` doesn't initialize the `dim` member. This `dim` is later used in many member functions while it's value is not initialized. You can fix it by:

```
  RealVector(const int _dim) : dim{_dim}
  {
     tab=new double[dim];
  }
```

*The second* bug is that the `dim` in the `operator+` belongs to the current object and might be bigger than `dim` of the `o` object. You should use `std::min(dim, o.dim)` instead.

*The third* one (thanks to [Mooing Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck) for pointing out) is that you are missing the `operator=` implementation. The default assignment operator performs just a 'flat' copy. Since you are using dynamic memory allocation it is critical to implement the 'deep' copy in the `operator=`. You can find the examples [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

**EDIT**

Since the `c++11` has been tagged here, I would strongly recommend using [smart pointers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541067/Cplusplus-Smart-Pointers) as well as [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) and [move assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment).